# Choosing specific lines from a file

Tags: python, split

I have a text file with entries

```
***********************
*    Row   * totalEven *
************************
*        0 *    125000 *
************************
************************
*    Row   * totalEven *
************************
*        0 *    340000 *
*        1 *    159000 *
************************
************************
*    Row   * totalEven *
************************
*        0 *   1360000 *
*        1 *   1440000 *
*        2 *   1440000 *
*        3 *   1380000 *
*        4 *   1350000 *
*        5 *   1440000 *
*        6 *   1440000 *
*        7 *   1440000 *
*        8 *   1440000 *
*        9 *   1422000 *
*       10 *    180000 *
```

and it goes like this for 6000 more lines. I need to get numbers from the 2nd column and sum them up. To choose such a line, I said

```
f = open(afile,'r')                                                                                                                                                                                                  
for i, l in enumerate(f):
    if l=="*    Row   * totalEven *" and (l=='************************'):                                                                                                                            
        continue
    else:
        nEv = l.split('*')[2] #here it chooses the 2nd column of the line
```

but it gives me an output with numbers on the third column, empty lines and lines with " totalEven". Then I also tried using `if re.search('*    Row   * totalEven *', l):` but it gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thecode.py", line 77, in <module>
    main()
  File "thecode.py", line 45, in main
    iArr = getFileValue('rootOut',iArr)
  File "thecode.py", line 62, in getFileValue
    if re.search('*    Row   * totalEven *', l):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/re.py", line 142, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/re.py", line 245, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions/solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your Boolean logic is incorrect:

```
if l=="*    Row   * totalEven *" and (l=='************************'):
```

How can this ever evaluate to `True`?  The input line can never equal both of those strings simultaneously.  I think you needed an `or`, rather than `and`.  Perhaps even better:

```
if l != "*    Row   * totalEven *" and \
   l != '************************': 
        nEv = l.split('*')[2] # Choose the 2nd column of the line
```

Now, note that `[2]` chooses the third column, not the 2nd: Python has zero-based indexing.  You could simplify this by taking the *last* column:

```
    nEv = l.split('*')[-1] # Chooses the right-most column of the line
```

**Correction**

Since you have column delimiters on the margins as well, there will be an empty string on each end of the list, such as

```
 ['', '   1   ', '  1440000 ', '']
```

The column you want is either `[2]` or `[-2]`.

Comment: ahh yes, I agree that it should be or. I guess I was tired enough. -1 doesn't work, I all get is empty lines. 2 works but still it also gives an output with ` totalEven ` along with the numbers and empty lines. other solution with `and \` does the same

Comment: I've tried running the updated code on your given input, and it produces only the desired numbers.  Since we don't have a way to reproduce the problem you're getting with `totalEven`, we can't fix it.  I am quite suspicious that the problem is in having the test string not quite matching your input.  Also, please note that this is (1) a separate error, warranting a separate ticket, and (2) something you can likely debug with basic methods: `print` the exact strings you're comparing.  (3) Try a more robust test, such as `totalEven in l`, rather than exact equality.

Answer (score 2):

The flaw that [Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4785185/prune) found in the logic is absolutely correct.

However, if you want a regex-based solution, here you go..

```
import re

with open(afile,'r') as infile:
    input_list = infile.readlines()
    final_summation = 0
    for input_string in input_list:
        temp_list = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', input_string))
        if len(temp_list) > 0:
            final_summation += int(temp_list[-1])

print(final_summation)
```

Comment: thank you! this works. can you explain me what does this line mean? `temp_list = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', input_string)`. I am not good at reg ex.

Comment: this also splits the digits after point (forgot to tell, they show up later). how can we change this to keep floats?

Answer (score 1):

try this one too.

```
f = open('./samplestring.txt','r')                                                                                                                                                                                                  
nums = []
for l in f.readlines():
    finds = re.findall('\d+',l.strip())
    if(len(finds) == 2):
        nums.append(int(finds[1]))
sum(nums)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. it works but also splits the digits after point (forgot to tell, they show up later). how can we change this to keep floats?

Comment: simply change int() to float()

Answer (score 0):

Change your eval as :

```
 If not 'totalEven' in l and not '*****' in l:
    Dothe job
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    sum = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        try:
           sum = (int(line[15:len(line)-3]))+ sum
        except:
            pass
print("The sum is {} ".format(sum))
```

**The result:**

```
The sum is 14956000
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build your regular expression in such a way that it returns the numbers you want to add directly taking into account the pattern on each line:

```
import re
with open(afile) as f:
    total = sum(int(number) for number in re.findall("\d *\* *(\d+)",f.read()))
```